How can I wire multiple receptacles to one switch with power coming to the switch first
I have five outlets I'm trying to wire to one switch my power source is at the switch something I've done is not right because when I turn on the switch it pops a breaker

This should be a simple circuit with black to black and white(neutral) to white.  If this is done, it might be as simple as a hot/switch hot screw touching the metal box or a ground wire too close.  Pictures and/or how the wires are connected will help.

Easiest start is a picture of the switch and connections in the junction box.

Assumptions: US/Canada and cables rather than individual wires.
In switch box:

Cable 1 (from breaker) = hot (black), neutral (white)
Cable 2 (to first receptacle) = switched hot (black), neutral (white)

Whites together with a wire nut.
Blacks go to the two switch screws. Doesn't matter top/bottom or left/right as long as this is a "dumb" switch. If it is a smart (WiFi, timer, etc.) switch then everything will be different - update question with specific model of switch. If it is a GFCI "deadfront"/switch, see below.
In each receptacle box, except the last one:

Cable 1 (from switch box or previous receptacle) = switched hot (black)/neutral (white)
Cable 2 (to next receptacle) = switched hot (black)/neutral (white)

One cable goes to one pair hot/neutral screws and the other cable goes to the other pair of hot/neutral screws. Common convention (because it is a few cents cheaper to manufacture this way) is that one side of a duplex receptacle is hot and the other side is neutral. The side with the larger slots is neutral, the side with the smaller slots is switched hot.
In the last receptacle box you just connect the one cable to hot/neutral (either top or bottom, your choice).
Note that if you require GFCI (kitchen, bathroom, laundry room, unfinished basement, garage, etc.) then you have three options:

GFCI/breaker - no change to the above directions
GFCI/receptacle - I do not recommend that here. If you do that, the GFCI/receptacle must be the first receptacle and the wiring will be very different from the above information. Ask for details if needed.
GFCI/deadfront - This is what I would recommend if you don't already have a GFCI/breaker, just make sure it is switch rated. This is the same size as a GFCI/receptacle but it doesn't have a place for you to plug things in. Instead, it just has TEST/OFF and RESET/ON buttons, which you can use for testing the GFCI function, for resetting the GFCI after a test or after an actual ground fault and as ON/OFF switch. If you use this, then cable 1 (from the breaker) goes to the "line" or "incoming power" screws and cable 2 (to the first receptacle) goes to the "load" or "protected power" or similar (names vary) screws.


The way you described is the way I have it wired hot comes into the switch box I got the hot wire on the switch neutral wires wire noted together the Hot leg goes out I have hot neutral in the proper places on every receptacle down the line I have looked over this thing 10 times find a short I can't find one and it still pops the breaker every time I throw the switch is there something else I can be missing here

@Travis  check the ground wires and the switch being too close to the box.  This is a common short with switches.  Why some people run tape around the switch screws.  Check the receptacles also for ground wires touching hot screws.  It might be the way the switch/receptacle goes back into the box.

Thanks a million sometimes you just got to stand back and look at it with fresh eyeballs I found it you're exactly right on the ground wires is too close to the hot screw in the box on the switch been to wire out of the way everything works perfectly once again thanks a million you're a lifesaver
